# Sequelize Upsert without primary key value in arguments

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, hapi.js

So, I have a relation which has the autogenerated `id` as the primary key and I want it to be that way.

The issue is that whenever I call `upsert()`, it seems like I have to provide for the primary key value as well in the parameter object which is insane as I wouldn't know what is the `id` of the particular row I want to edit.

Instead, I am sending mandatorily the value for a `unique` key that I have defined, but it doesn't work.

Any workarounds or do I need to shift my primary key to some other key of whose value is known?

> Example:  Let's say I have an `Employee` table where I have the Employee Id as the PK and their emails as the UNIQUE key. Now, I believe that an `upsert` operation can still be carried out using a unique key, but that doesn't seem to be possible and I have to tag in the primary key for it.

Comment: Can you put your code? Sequelize works fine with PostgreSQL nextval()

Comment: I don't think any ocde is necessary, but I will put an example statement.

Comment: The code is necessary. To help you I need two things: the code for sequelize and the console of sequelize (that is the query that generates sequelize). In PostgreSQL there is not an `UPSERT` function, instead it uses `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...` With that information it's easy to find whats going on.